# How can I decompile my DLL file using an existing PDB file to get my code back so it's recognizable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, missing-data, dotpeek

I have been working on a personal MVC project for about 5 months straight now. I just finished 2 days ago and yesterday I was trying to use Azure to host it as well as creating and connecting GitHub to back it up. I am not very good at using GitHub, so that was probably the problem. At some point, my `Project Solution` file, `wwwroot` folder, `model` folder, `viewmodel` folder, `view` folder, and `controller` folder just disappeared and I now cannot get on my project. I looked around in the recycling bin, looked at AppData/local, tried restoring my computer to Sept 5, and I feel like I tried everything.

However, I have the `DLL` and `PDB` files for the project. I used dotPeek to decompile the DLL but the results have a bunch of code I didn't put on it and the variables are insane. Also, the decompiled views might as well be unusable because it is not in HTML. Is there a way I can use the PDB for my original project to decompile the DLL to more resemble the code I wrote to make this process less painful?